# Como puedo generalizar un parámetro para arrays grandes en Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, visualización-de-datos

he conseguido visualizar de manera correcta estos arrays en chart js:

```
var labelsValue = ['manzanas','peras','naranjas'] 
var dataValue = ['22','24','25']
var colours = ['#003559', '#4C6B8B', '#005B99']

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Project1'],

        datasets: [      
          
            {
                label:[labelsValue[0]],
                data: [dataValue[0]],
                backgroundColor: [colours[0]]                 
            },
            {
                label: [labelsValue[1]],
                data: [dataValue[1]],
                backgroundColor: [colours[1]]
            },
            {
                label: [labelsValue[2]],
                data: [dataValue[2]],
                backgroundColor: [colours[2]]
            }               
        ]  
    },
...
```

Y ahora me gustaría generalizarlo para arrays mucho mas grandes (pongamos, por ejemplo, que "labelsValue", "dataValue" y "colours" fueran de 183 elementos cada uno, en lugar de 3). Para ello intento utilizar:

```
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Project1'],

            datasets: function () {
                for (let i = 0; i < labelsValue.length; i++) {
                    label += labelsValue[i],
                    data += dataValue[i],
                    backgroundColor += colours[i]
                }
                return (label, data, backgroundColor)
            }   
...
```

Pero no consigo que funcione, como podría hacerlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe construir el array porfuera de la propiedad de chartjs , y por último los añade a

```
datasets: superArrayDeObjetos;
```